# ggplot facet y vertically wrapped

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I would like to make a histogram using facet_grid with multiple facets on the y axis with angle 0. The way shown below but it keeps all the facets in one line. How can I get each facet in a different line to minimize the width of the y facet boxes? If there is a solution where the label remains that would be great.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars,(aes(x = mpg))) + geom_histogram(bins = 5) + facet_grid(vs+am~., labeller = label_both)
p <- p + theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe try `facet_wrap` instead of `facet_grid`? The point of `facet_grid` is to keep things in rows and columns.

Comment: I would like to keep the plots themselves grided but change the facet labels so they are one on top of the other.

Comment: To clarify: do you want the strip labels as two-line labels or do you want to place the strips on top of the panels?

Comment: Ah, wasn't really sure what you meant by "facet boxes". They're generally called "strip labels".

Comment: Do you mean that you want a line break in the strip label, e.g., `am: 0 <linebreak> vs: 0`?

Comment: yes, each label on a different line